# How to extract the helm values.yaml of my existing helm deployment (Name : prime-gitlab)

Tags: kubernetes, ldap, kubernetes-helm

I have deployed Gitlab from gitlab official helm chart. When I deployed it I didn't enable LDAP. Be informed that I didn't edit the values.yaml rather I used `helm update --install XXX` command to do it.

My question is how do I extract the helm values.yaml of my existing helm deployment (Name: `prime-gitlab`). I know how to use `helm value show` command to download the value.yaml from the gitlab / artifactoryhub but here I would like extract my existing value.yaml so I can edit the LDAP part in the values.yaml file.

```
01:36 AM  ✔ root on my-k8s-man-01 Δ [~] Ω  helm ls -n prime-gitlab
NAME        NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART           APP VERSION
prime-gitlab    prime-gitlab    1           2022-02-12 01:02:15.901215658 -0800 PST deployed    gitlab-5.7.2    14.7.2
```

Comment: Do you need [`helm get values`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_values/)?

Comment: Exactly. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The answer here is very short. Exactly, like @DavidMaze mentioned in comments section you're looking for [`helm get values`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_values/).

To this command one can use several options.

> This command downloads a values file for a given release.
>
> ```
> helm get values RELEASE_NAME [flags]
> ```

*Options:*

```
  -a, --all             dump all (computed) values
  -h, --help            help for values
  -o, --output format   prints the output in the specified format. Allowed values: table, json, yaml (default table)
      --revision int    get the named release with revision
```